で vs に with ご一緒
In this sentence why is the で particle used?:
''初めまして今日からこの部屋でご一緒させて頂くことになった''
I know the particle is used for locations of actions but ''ご一緒'' is just a state of being isn't it? ''Being together'' So why does it work?

Well, firstly, “ご一緒する” can be argued to be active. It's a humble expression that means “to join” or “to accompany”. It just so happens that the idea that “〜で” can't be used with stative verbs is also wrong:
I know that it's often taught that “〜で” is used for locations of actions and “〜に” for states. I wish it weren't because it's the point where it's such a simplification that it's actually better not taught since it doesn't even apply to 10% of all verbs I'd say. In reality “ある” and “いる” are the two main verbs that use “〜に” to mark their location, but for instance “人気がある” uses “〜で” again. I feel it's better to learn that “〜で” marks location in space, “〜に” in time, but that there are some exceptions to this idea. The majority of stative clauses still use “〜で” to mark their location, but “ある”, “いる”, and “多い” are simply very common ones that use “〜に” for it.
Furthermore, it's often said that “〜に” marks direction towards in active verbs, but that's too has many exceptions. “教わる” and “もらう” use it to mark direction from, not towards, “持つ” is interesting in that it uses “〜に” to mark the place where the object is held specifically but uses “〜で” to mark the place where the holding takes place. “いい”　uses “〜に” to mark what something is good for, not the location where it is good.
So basically, one would better learn the general rule that “〜で” marks location in space, and what “〜に” marks depends on the verb and has to be learned with the verb, and yes, many verbs of movement use it for their destination, but some like “歩く” or “泳ぐ” can't use it for their destination, and some use it for their origin, and yet others mark entirely different things with it, and as said “いる" and “ある” use it for the location of existing, so “〜で” isn't use for that any more, but many combinations with either such as “人気がある” use “〜で” for location  again; it uses “〜に” to mark whom it's popular with, incidentally.
In this example, it indeed simply means something like “I have received the privilege to join you in this room starting from today.” ignoring the kind of weird translation of “させて頂くことになった。” which has no proper translation, but let's say that “この部屋でご一緒する”  indeed just means “to join you in this room”

Very good and concise answer. Thanks for the explanation
